# Possible Typo in Manipulation of Expressions

Tags: arithmetic

Someone claimed that the following two expressions are equal. But after much manipulation, I cannot establish their equality. Is there in fact a typo somewhere?

$C(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{-(a+p)/2} x_1^p$
$C(x_1)^{-a}(1+x_2/x_1)^{-(a+p)/2}$

I did find that the first expression is equal to $C(x_1^2)^{-(a+p)/2}(1+x_2^2/x_1^2)^{-(a+p)/2}x_1^p$, but did manage to make any more progress.

Comment: They are not identically equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the second expression. The term $1+x_2/x_1$ within it should be $1+(x_2)^2/(x_1)^2.$